# What values of $k$ if any will make matrices $AB = BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1\\
    1 & -1\\ 
  \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$B
 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & k\\
    -1 & 2\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

I need to find a value of $k$ that will make $AB = BA$.

I multiplied the two matrices and found no such value of k. Does that mean that there is no value of k that makes $AB = BA$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

No matter what $k$ is, the lower left element of $AB$ will be $2$ and the same element of $BA$ will be $0$. So these are never equal.